# Vue 2 js replacing 1 image from v-for img src

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a grid with 3 columns that I fit with images that has img-src given by axios in my webpage.

```
<div class="row my-row" v-for="(banner, index) in bannerArray" :key="index">
  <div class="banner-section">
    <div class="banner-name">
      <h3>{{banner.banner_position}}</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="preview-home-banner">
      <img :src="bannerArray[index].banner_url" alt="image_banner" class="image-banner">
    </div>
          <div class="row my-row">
            <input type="file" id="file-upload" accept="image/png, image/jpg ,image/jpeg" @change="onFileChange(index)"/>
          </div>
</div>

data () {
    return {
      file: null,
      bannerArray: [],
      showNotifModal: false,
      homeBannerPreview: null,
      contactUsBannerPreview: null,
      aboutBannerPreview: null,
      communityBannerPreview: null
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.getBannerList()
  },
  methods: {
    getBannerList () {
      axios.get(ConfigFile.basic_url + '/banner/get_all').then((response) => {
        this.bannerArray = response.data.data
        this.homeBannerPreview = this.bannerArray[0].banner_url
        this.contactUsBannerPreview = this.bannerArray[1].banner_url
        this.aboutBannerPreview = this.bannerArray[2].banner_url
        this.communityBannerPreview = this.bannerArray[3].banner_url
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      })
    },
    onFileChange (e) {
      this.file = e.target.files[0]
      this.bannerArray[0].banner_url = URL.createObjectURL(this.file)
    }
  }
```

How do I replace one of the individual image cell img-src in my grid then render it after change?

Comment: It looks like `bannerArray` is a data attribute so it should be responsive. So all you need to do it update the url in your bannerArray and the page should re-render it for you. `this.bannerArray[index].banner_url = '/some/url/to/an/image.jpg'`

Comment: i did       this.bannerArray[0].banner_url = URL.createObjectURL(this.file)
but no changge the file is inputed but the image not changed sir @bassxzero

Comment: Post your component definition.

Comment: done sir @bassxzero

Comment: This event handler never gets called right? `onFileChange(e)`

Comment: i added the rest of code that contain onFileChangeFunction @bassxzero

Comment: I think if you perform the following changes, it should work:
`<input type="file" id="file-upload" accept="image/png, image/jpg ,image/jpeg" @change="onFileChange($event, index)"/>` and 
`onFileChange (e, idx) {
      this.file = e.target.files[0]
      this.bannerArray[idx].banner_url = URL.createObjectURL(this.file)
    }`

Comment: You're passing the index to the event handler and calling it `e` so `e.target.files` is probably null. Try this `@change="onFileChange($event, index)"` instead of `@change="onFileChange(index)"`

Comment: Thank you very much sir @bassxzero God Bless You

Comment: don't forget to also write at the correct index in your bannerArray ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing the `index` to the event handler and calling it `e` so `e.target.files` is probably null.

Change this

```
<input type="file" id="file-upload" accept="image/png, image/jpg ,image/jpeg" @change="onFileChange(index)"/>
```

To this

```
<input type="file" id="file-upload" accept="image/png, image/jpg ,image/jpeg" @change="onFileChange($event, index)"/>
```

And this

```
onFileChange (e) {
      this.file = e.target.files[0]
      this.bannerArray[0].banner_url = URL.createObjectURL(this.file)
    }
```

to this

```
onFileChange (e, i) {
      this.file = e.target.files[0]
      this.bannerArray[i].banner_url = URL.createObjectURL(this.file)
    }
```